# C++ storing functions and operators in a structure

Tags: c++, function, model, structure

How to improve a data structure for storing functions in arithmetic parser converting from infix to postfix notation?

At this moment I am using an array of char arrays:

```
char *funct[] = { "sin", "cos", "tan"... }
char text[] = "tan";
```

This impementation is a little bit confused and leads to the following comparisions, if we test char to be a function

```
if ( strcmp ( funct[0], text) == 0 ) || ( strcmp ( funct[1], "text ) == 0 ) || ( strcmp ( func[2], text) == 0 ))
{
  ... do something
}
```

( or to the for cycle version).

If there are a lot of functions (and a lot of comparisions), the index referencing leads to errors and it is not clear. There is also a necessity to change the index when we remove/add a new function....

How to improve such a structure so as it is easy to read, easy to maintain and easy to scale up?

I was thinking about enum

```
typedef enum
{
  Fsin=0,
  Fcos,
  Ftan
} TFunctions;
```

which results to

```
if ( strcmp ( funct[Fsin], text) == 0 ) || ( strcmp ( funct[Fcos], "text ) == 0 ) || ( strcmp ( func[Ftan], text) == 0 ))
{
...
```

but there may be a better solution...

Comment: Are you writing C or C++ code? You've labelled the question as C++, but the code you posted is C, not C++. It's also not quite clear what you're trying to achieve with the comparisons.

Comment: You can have a `std::array` or `std::vector` of `std::string`s and use `std::find`.

Comment: Is the second example correct? If you use an enum you could use a straight `switch` to do operator-specific handling.

Comment: @ Timo: It is a part of c++ code, but I try to design it as fast as possible. Therefore, these operations are C-like....

Comment: @justik, I think you'll be surprised how small the performance difference is if you're using the correct C++ idioms and you might find that with a decent standard library implementation, there is none or the C++ implementation might be faster.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil (Donald Knuth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use std::map.

```
enum functions
{
    sin,
    cos,
    tan
};

std::map<std::string, unsigned char> func_map;
func_map["sin"] = sin;
func_map["cos"] = cos;
func_map["tan"] = tan;

// then:
std::string text = "cos";

std::map<char*, unsigned char>::iterator it;
it = func_map.find(text);

if(it != func_map.end())
{
    // ELEMENT FOUND
    unsigned char func_id = it->second;
}
else
{
    // NOT FOUND
}
```

Comment: Storing raw char* (or pointers of any kind) into a std::map or any other std container is not really a good idea (to put it mildly). It's been well documented that they don't play nicely with raw pointers and weren't intended to. In the above case, the find() function will compare pointers to strings rather than the string values being pointed to, which is not going to give you the results you expect. I would replace the key with a std::string, which will fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

For fastest code you may have some kind of map as follow:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, func_t> func_map;
func_map fm;
fm["sin"] = sin_func(); // get value of this entry from somewhere
fm["cos"] = cos_func(); // for example sin_func or cos_func

auto i = fm.find( "sin" );
if( i != fm.end() ) {
    func_t f = i->second; // value found, we may use it.
}
```

Also if there is really a lot of items you may use `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`